# Tailwind conditional transition

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm creating a collapse/accordion component that shows the content when clicked. I want to add a little delay to that action but what I've doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have:

```
const Accordion = ({ children, open }) => {
  const contentSpace = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div
        ref={contentSpace}
        className={clsx(
          'overflow-auto overflow-y-hidden h-0 transition-height duration-700 ease-in-out',
          {
            'h-full': open,
          }
        )}
      >
        <div className="py-2">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have to use numeric values in order to make the animation work. So I had to change h-full with a numeric height.